# How to factorize $x^5 -1=0$?

Tags: calculus

how can I factorize $x^5 -1 =0 $ so I get a quartic equation separately. Is there any specific way of factorizing such equations to get something of a lesser power?

Comment: To factor that equation, you'll need to solve the expression $x^5 -1$.

Comment: It's not clear if @BolzWeir is playing with language or is also misusing the terminology, but we *solve* equations, and we *factorize* polynomials. So it makes no sense to "factorize $x^5-1=0$," but it does make sense to "factorize $x^5-1$.

Answer (score 8):

Useful identity: $x^n-1=(x^{n-1}+\cdots+x+1)(x-1)$.

Comment: To see that this is true the concept of "telescoping sum" can be useful.

Comment: Here's a more general version of that identity:

$$x^n-y^n=(x-y)\left(\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}x^{n-1-i}y^i\right)$$

Comment: Good point both of you.

Comment: Is there a name for this identity?

Answer (score 6):

Divide $x^5-1$ by $x-1$ to get
$$x^5-1=(x-1)(x^4+x^3+x^2+x+1).$$
Now note that
$$x^4+x^3+x^2+x+1=\left(x^2+\frac 12x+1\right)^2-\frac 54x^2$$
$$=\left(x^2+\frac 12x+1-\frac{\sqrt 5}{2}x\right)\left(x^2+\frac 12x+1+\frac{\sqrt 5}{2}x\right).$$

Hence, one has
$$x^5-1=(x-1)\left(x^2+\frac{1-\sqrt 5}{2}x+1\right)\left(x^2+\frac{1+\sqrt 5}{2}x+1\right).$$

Comment: this is working backing backwards; with the knowledge $x = e^{2ik/5}$ are roots of $x^5 - 1.$ no idea how helpful this is to the op.

Answer (score 2):

$$x^5-1=0\implies x^5=1$$

The solutions are the fifth roots of unity.

$$\large x=e^{2\pi i\frac{k}{5}}~,~k\in\Bbb{Z}~\land~0\leq k\lt 5$$

For each solution $a$, you have a factor $(x-a)$ thus giving you the five factors.

Answer (score 1):

The equation $z^n=\omega_0$ has the solution's:

$$z_k=\sqrt[n]{|\omega_0|}\left(cos\frac{\arg(\omega_0)+2k\pi}{n}\right)+i\sin\left(\frac{\arg(\omega_0)+2k\pi}{n}\right)\,\,,\,\,k=0,1,...,n-1$$

And the solution of the equation $z^n=1$, are $z_k=\cos(\frac{2k\pi}{n})+i\sin(\frac{2k\pi}{n})\,\,,\,\,k=0,1,...,n-1$

Answer (score 0):

Look for roots of the polynomial. For example, $x=1$ should be immediately apparent as a root of $x^5-1$. This means the quantity $x^5-1$ is divisible by $x-1$. Simply compute the polynomial division of $$\frac{x^5-1}{x-1} = P_4(x)$$ to get a fourth degree polynomial $P_4(x)$. Thus $x^5-1$ can be factored as $$x^5-1 = (x-1)P_4(x)$$ You could continue factoring $P_4(x)$, although the roots may be complex. If there are complex roots there will either be two or four of them.